# SharePoint Calendar Synced with Outlook but can't update from Outlook

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, permissions, calendar, sync

I synced a SharePoint Calendar to my Outlook.  Did the "Connect to Outlook" option, when the pop screen appeared, I clicked on Advanced and it stated that I have Read permissions only when I know I have Full Control.
Well I'm able to view the SharePoint Calendar in my Outlook however, when I make any updates in Outlook, I receive an Send/Receive error, 
***Task 'SharePoint' reported error (0x8007005):  You do not have permission to view this SharePoint List***
Is this by design?  Or is this a permissions issues?  I noticed that the adding something on SharePoint is a form but the one in Outlook is the standard Outlook email style message.

Comment: After further diving into this, there is one person who is able to do the two-way communication.  He has two accounts in the permissions groups while everyone else has one.  The one extra one is his Windows login.  Also, when you go to the People and Group settings, and click on someone and you see their profile, everyone, including the person that is able to do the 2-way, it shows a 500 server error.  However when you click on the Windows login, you see their profile page.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, we cannot update SharePoint Calendar in Outlook. You can only view the SharePoint Calendar in outlook